# Axios remove default headers for one request

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to get a location from the Google Maps API but i get a CORS Policy Error because i have these default headers in my bootstrap.js

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
};
```

How do i remove them for a specific axios get request? I saw some answers were they used before the request

```
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common["X-CSRF-TOKEN"];
```

But these will delete them entirely, any ideas? Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `transformRequest` in the request you are making:

```
axios.get('xxxx.com', { transformRequest: [(data, headers) => {
   delete headers.common.Authorization;

   return data 
}] })
```

Or you could delete the header directly and then add it back after:

```
delete axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];
axios.get('xxxx.com');
axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = 'Bearer xxxx';
```

Comment: `transformRequest` would only work for the request methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'PATCH' and 'DELETE', it does not work for request method GET, Axios Documentation : https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config

Comment: @being_j OP wants to modify headers. Not the body. As per the RFC 2616 a GET request should not have a body. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-4.3